# Second exists condition does not work

Tags: javascript, exists

I'm having a question about javascript where I have two conditions to check if the input fields exists. But it only shows me that "opleiding exists" and not that "opleiding exists" and "domein exists".

please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Thanks very much !

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()
{
    var opleiding = document.getElementById("opleiding");
    var domein = document.getElementById("domein");

    if(document.getElementById("opleiding")){
        document.write("opleiding exists");
    }

    if (document.getElementById("domein")){
        document.write("domein exists");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="domein" value="domein" />
<input type="hidden" id="opleiding" value="opleiding" />

<div id="button" onclick="submit()">
<strong>button text</strong>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read how [document write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) works.

Comment: `document.write` will overwrite the previous data in  the page

Comment: Change your `document.write` to `alert` and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` will override the existing content in the page. That's the reason why you're seeing only on message.

You must use `document.body.appendChild` instead to show both error messages.

```js
function submit()
{
var opleiding = document.getElementById("opleiding");
var domein = document.getElementById("domein");
var textElement;
if(document.getElementById("opleiding")){
    textElement = document.createElement("p");
    textElement.textContent = "opleiding exists";
    document.querySelector("#results").appendChild(textElement);
}

if (document.getElementById("domein")){
    textElement = document.createElement("p");
    textElement.textContent = "domein exists";
    document.querySelector("#results").appendChild(textElement);
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="domein" value="domein" />
<input type="hidden" id="opleiding" value="opleiding" />
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="button" onclick="submit()">
<strong>button text</strong>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **avoid using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)**, since that it's a deprecated method. When you use it the first time, it will write down what you want, but **remove all the content of the page**, as per its definition.

To do what you want you should "write" using either `document.body.appendChild` to append some element (like a `<div>`) containing text, or add some text to the `document.body.innerHTML`, here's an example:

```
function submit() {
    var opleiding_div = document.createElement('div'),
        domein_div = document.createElement('div');

    opleiding_div.textContent = "opleiding exists";
    domein_div.textContent = "domein exists";

    if(document.getElementById("opleiding")){
        document.body.appendChild(opleiding_div);
    }

    if (document.getElementById("domein")){
        document.body.appendChild(domein_div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your explaination :D